# After adding a new Post and trying to edit the same post, field remains empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vee-validate, v-model

```
<template>
  <div class="card m-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <Form method="post" @submit="submitData" :validation-schema="schema" ref="myForm" v-slot="{ errors, isSubmitting, handleReset }">
         <div class="form-group col-5">
            <Field name="id" type="hidden" class="form-control"  v-model="id" />
            <Field name="title" type="text" class="form-control" :placeholder="'Title'" v-model="post.title"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.title }"/>
            <ErrorMessage name="title" />
          </div>
          <br/>
           <div class="form-group col-5">
            <Field name="author" type="text" class="form-control" :placeholder="'Author'"  v-model="post.author" :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.author }"/>
            <ErrorMessage name="author" />
          </div>
          <br /><br />
          <b-button variant="primary" type="submit" :disabled="isSubmitting" :class="{ 'submitting': isSubmitting }"> {{ buttonText }}</b-button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <b-button variant="warning" @click="handleReset">Reset</b-button><br/>
      </Form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" v-if="list != undefined && list.length">
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="post in list" :key="post.id">
        <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.author }}</td>
        <td>
          <b-button variant="info" v-on:click="getEditUserDetails(post.id)"
            >Edit</b-button
          >
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h1 v-else>No Records Found</h1>
</template>


<script>
import { createApp } from "vue";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import axios from "axios";
import App from "../App.vue";
import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "vee-validate";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueAxios, axios);

export default {
  name: "Posts",
  components: {
    Form,
    Field,
    ErrorMessage,
  },
  data() {
   return {
      post: {
        title: null,
        author: null,
      },
      list: undefined,
      isEditMode: false,
      id: null,
      buttonText: "Add",
    };
  },
  computed:{
    schema() {
      return Yup.object({
      title: Yup.string().required("Title is required").nullable(),
      author: Yup.string().required("Author is required").nullable(),
    });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUsers();
  },
  methods: {
    submitData() {
      if (this.isEditMode) {
        axios
          .put("http://localhost:3000/posts/" + this.id, this.post)
          .then(() => {
            this.isEditMode = false;
            this.buttonText = this.isEditMode ? "Edit" : "Add";
            this.id = null;
        });
      } else {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/posts", this.post).then(() => {
          this.buttonText = this.isEditMode ? "Edit" : "Add";
        });
      }
      this.getUsers();
    },
    getUsers() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/posts").then((result) => {
        this.list = result.data;
      });
    },
    getEditUserDetails(id) {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/posts/" + id).then((result) => {
        this.id = result.data.id;
        this.post.title = result.data.title;
        this.post.author = result.data.author;
        this.isEditMode = true;
        this.buttonText = this.isEditMode ? "Edit" : "Add";
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

My vue/cli version is 4.5.13, vee-validate version is 4.4.11 and vue-axios version is 3.3.6

Whenever I add new data ad trying to edit immediately same data but v-model is not getting an update, so my input field remains empty, and when clicking on another available post and again clicking on added post it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably losing reactivity because of `list: undefined`  data. I assume that you are receiving an array from your `axios.get()`

Saying that, I would try:

```
 data() {
   return {
      post: {
        title: null,
        author: null,
      },
      list: [], // Define default value as an array
      isEditMode: false,
      id: null,
      buttonText: "Add",
    };
  },

....

methods: {
  ....
  
    getUsers() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/posts").then((result) => {
        this.list = [ ...result.data]
      })
    },
}
```

And for your table

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" v-if="list.length">
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="post in list" :key="post.id">
        <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.author }}</td>
        <td>
          <b-button variant="info" v-on:click="getEditUserDetails(post.id)"
            >Edit</b-button
          >
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h1 v-else>No Records Found</h1>
```

Comment: But main issue is not about list and getUsers, main issue is in getEditUserDetails in then block    where result data are set to post object         
 this.post.title = result.data.title;
 this.post.author = result.data.author;